# Bluetooth connection with many devices

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I want to create a network which includes many bluetooth devices paired to my smartphone. I've already found information that there can be 7 devices connected at the same time.

Probably I will have more than 7 devices, but they will be woken up from time to time, so I figured that it's possible. Just randomly devices will be sending data to smartphone App and then they will go into sleep mode.

But sometimes it's possible that more than 7 devices will try to connect at the same time. Is is possible to make a queue? Or should I force devices to try to reconnect to smartphone couple of times?

What do you think?

PS. They won't stream music or any other "limited" data.

Comment: I have implemented an IoT app somewhat along the same lines, what I have experienced is once you go above 6 connections. The Bluetooth stack really can't handle the overhead and starts breaking any connection made afterward. Moreover, you will also find many devices which won't be able to make even more than 1 connection but these will be very old devices running on kitkat/lollipop

Comment: Thanks Gautam :)
Did it disconnect already connected devices?

Comment: Yes it will automatically disconnect the peripheral device and you have to reconnect again

Comment: That's a bad news :(
It's gonna be IoT project too. 

How did you solve that issue?

Comment: We didn't since its a limitation, so we explicitly told our end users that you can't connect more than 7 peripheral devices. Also, we made sure if less than 7 are there then we try to reconnect it asap

Comment: As I said - I want to pair more than 7, but all of them will be on standby and randomly they are going to:
1. Wake up,
2. Connect to smartphone,
3. Send data
4. Switch to sleep mode.

But it's possible that some time there are going to be more than 7 same time. 
I need to think through how to solve that ;)

Answer (score 0):

For your scenarios where you want to pair more than 7 devices, and as you are following step by step process for each device to connect and transfer data, better you create a queue. You can design it on a state machine, which picks the device from queue when state says available, then go to each state until sync and transfer is done, and come back to available state where it can pick the next device to continue.

Even for the cases where we try to connect more than 5 devices, I have experienced frequent connection drop and difficult to rely for data transfer in case where device may loose the stored data in case of drop.